# UIscrollview and uibuttons tap

Tags: ios, scrollview

I am using a UIScrollView where I got some UIButtons, to recognize that I pressed the button above, I created a subclass of UIScrollView where rewrite the method

```
- (BOOL) touchesShouldCancelInContentView (UIView *) view
```

but only enters that method when the touch is a journey, never comes when I press on the screen without more.

the UIScrollView I've created thus:

`

```
CGSize containerSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 480.0f);
CGSize containerSize2 = CGSizeMake(640.0f, 960.0f);
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollViewWithButtons alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=containerSize}];

[self.scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.5f];
[self.scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:1.0f];
[self.scrollView setZoomScale:0.5f];
[self.scrollView setDelegate:self];

self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
self.scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;
self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;

self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=containerSize2}];
self.containerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.containerView];

[self.scrollView setClipsToBounds:NO];

//instanciar uimageview
fondo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 960)];
[self.containerView addSubview:fondo];
[fondo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Grande.png"]];

self.scrollView.contentSize = containerSize2;
```

and button add

```
imagen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [imagen addTarget:self action:@selector(pulsadoIzq) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

        [imagen setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imagen setFrame:CGRectMake(xUser, yUser, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
        [imagen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.containerView addSubview:fichaUserIzq];

        imagen.center = CGPointMake(xUser, yUser);`enter code here`
```

I need to capture the tap on the screen to the buttons
How I can do?

I would also like to know because if I have implemented this code:

```
img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecg = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgDragged:)];

img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[img addGestureRecognizer:panRecg];
img.center = CGPointMake(160, 436);

[self.scrollView addSubview:img];
```

When I click on the image nothing happens, does not enter the method, only comes when I press and drag. I also want to capture when pressed over this image and so I capture only when the move.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I implement this method:

```
-(void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.scrollView];
if ((touchPoint.x > 88)&&(touchPoint.x < 226)&&(touchPoint.y > 172)&&(touchPoint.y < 319)) {
    if (rodando) {
        [self pararAnimacionDado];
    }
}
```

}

`UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];`